# What's the US slang term for "following someone in a car"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, american-english, slang, idiom-requests

I heard this somewhere on YouTube and I wish I could recall where exactly.  The person was recording himself from a dash-cam while driving, and when he noticed that a cop was following him, he said this to another person that was in a car with him

> Hey, hang on. That cop is **_________** me.

He used this slang word for *following me* that I'm curious to know.

I'm referring to American English slang.

Comment: ........tailing

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thanks, it's a good one. But he used something else.

Comment: *[Dogging](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog#Verb)*, pursuing with the intent to catch, also is a possibility.  Also *racially-profiling*, as in “Hey, hang on. That cop is racially-profiling me.”

Comment: tagging/trailing along/behind/after ?

Comment: "Tailing" is by far the most common term.  Next I would say "shadowing".  But there are apt to be a dozen different slang terms.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say **tailing**.  *That cop has been tailing me for a few blocks* sounds the most normal.

*Tailgating* is not quite what you're looking for—that implies following someone too close, and *shadowing* is for other contexts.

To further substantiate my answer (from the Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus)

> verb
> informal *the paparazzi tailed them*: follow, shadow, stalk, trail, track, hunt, hound, dog, pursue, chase.
>
> **on someone's tail** *a police car stayed on his tail*: CLOSE behind, following closely, (hard) on someone's heels.

From those examples, *stalk* adds a whole slew of other implications to it, *trail* is similar and sounds awkward to me, *hunt*, *hound*, and *dog* also add implications.  *Pursue* is also a good one, but isn't quite slang, is it?  And *chase* means to chase.

And, I have even more for you—if you're okay taking it beyond *slang*.  In my personal experiences driving around with my friends, I've said and heard things like *that guy's creeping* and *that guy's been on my ass for a few blocks now*.

#### Basically,

if the words suggested already aren't good enough for you, you have to make something up yourself.  Whatever works with people you know, in your area.  This guy on YouTube, I'd imagine, was doing just that.

Comment: Awesome, man. Thanks. I think what he used was, _"That cop is maddogging me."_

Comment: huh - it sounds like "dogging" or maybe "mad-dogging" is a **new slang** for "tailing".  thanks for that MikeF

Comment: Heh… that sounds a bit silly to me.

Comment: For reference, looks like *mad dogging* means to give someone a glaring look (according to top googled sources).

Comment: @GeorgePompidou: I know. But that's what slang is, _silly_. I believe that it might have been derived from "dogging", or maybe even vice-versa.

Comment: The *mad* in *mad-dogging* is an intensifier, like *mad money* to mean lots of cash and *mad love* to mean a deep sense of connection. A cop dogging you isn't good; it means he's been following you for a little while. A cop *mad-dogging* you means that you believe the cop is no only tailing you, but intent on following you until you screw up so that he can bust you.

Comment: @Kit that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

It might be **shadowing**. If you look up *tail* in a thesaurus, there are a few other colloquial terms if this isn't the one you are looking for. (trail, track, stalk, and others.)

In spycraft, [surveillance](http://www.instructables.com/id/spy-surveillance/step3/follow-the-rabbit/) techniques refer to the *eye* as the one tracking the *rabbit*. You could say that someone is **eyeing** your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word tailing. The cop isn't tailgating because that would mean that the cop is trailing close behind you, but doesn't necessarily mean that their following you. Tailing means they are following you.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE!  It's generally best to read existing answers before adding your own, as *tailing* and *tailgating* have been explained in previous answers.  New answers should add something new.

Answer (score -1):

hang on. That cop is ***on to*** me.

Answer (score -1):

Years ago when my friends and I would ride in separate cars, one following the other, we called it a **caravan**. I think I also heard that word used as a verb,
even if I did not, someone has probably used it that way, as in, "We're going to **caravan** to the party."

**Note:** I would simply have agreed with the answer "tailing", but OP already said that was not the word used in the video. So we're looking for other possibilities with less prior likelihood now.

Answer (score -1):

I've been "made."

The cop "made" me.

Comment: Please consider showing some support for this.

Comment: https://www.italki.com/question/86620?answer-sorting=3

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=made

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/188783/239160

Comment: @Jeremy What Drew is asking for is support in the answer itself. Please edit your answer. Comments are for making and discussing possible improvements to the answer, but not a good place to put those improvements. Comments are not easily searchable and they are often deleted.

Answer (score -7):

Tailgating.

The cop was tailgating him.

Comment: [tailgate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tailgate).