# to make, meaning to recognize

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I watched a movie (On the rocks) and saw this dialogue:

> A: I went to Sergeant O'Callaghan, Timmy... I went to his beefsteak
> for his retirement...
>
> B: That's my grandfather.
>
> A: That's right. Gosh,
> I don't know why I didn't make you right away. You're a ringer, dead
> ringer.

I checked all meanings of "make" but couldn't see any meaning close to "recognize". But it obviously means "to recognize" here, am I wrong?

Comment: It _is_ difficult to find...See: [to make someone](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+someone)

Comment: I had checked "make someone" too but got irrelevant results. Thank you so much!

Comment: As in spy movies too: "I've been made (they are on to me)".

Comment: If this is not VTCed heavily by EOD, I will post a real answer, in detail, tomorrow.

Comment: Explosive Ordinance Disposal?

Comment: Oh my Dog @MichaelHarvey ..."End of Day" (EOD) You must be retired longer than me.

Comment: Oh. We say CoP (Close of play) where I work.

Comment: _yo cumplí_ ...

Comment: What make is that SUV over there?

Comment: Duplicate of [Usage of the expression 'We have been made'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/usage-of-the-phrase-we-have-been-made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***to **make** someone***

> to identify someone.

Also:

> To identify one as a criminal or wrongdoer. Often used in passive constructions.

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+someone)

From the OP...

> **"I didn't *make you"*...**

This particular usage of the idiomatic phrasal verb hinges on a possibly obscure American usage, as sometimes heard in Network crime dramas.

In my searches in the 2 pages of the OALD covering the verb, I cannot find a definition that fits. So...I guess it is an Americanism, and slang of some sort.

Our usual GR is [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/make)...I cannot the usage there, or in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make), [McMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make_1), or [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make).

The normal phrase is passive in construction, such as ...

"He got made..."

As someone who worked both sides of the street in the 70s and 80s, I can attest that this is a real idiom.

Comment: General reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's _not_...find me a reference that defines it, apart from what I sourced. If you can, I will delete the A. As mentioned in my post, I cannot find it in OALD.

Comment: {"make someone" + meaning} takes one straight there. I'm pretty sure the Farlex Dictionary of Idioms is listed as being general reference, and the unusual usage marks this as being an idiom.

Comment: Our usual GR is Lexico...if the usage is not there, and not in Cambridge, and not in McMillan, and not in MW, and not in OALD...how is this GR? That is asking an OP to go above and beyond the normal. The Q is legit. Just let it go, OK? Isn't this part of our purpose here,  to define arcane terms?

Comment: You need to look on ELU.Meta for the list of works considered general reference. // It's a pretty well-known usage, in the UK as well as the US.

Comment: If it is so well-known, then it should be found in just about  any GR. With the exception of Farlex, it is not. That means it is not "General".

Comment: And, according to an answer at the duplicate, it's in OED, marked as 'slang'. And, as one would thus expect, in UD.  // If you prefer, I'll expand 'general reference' to 'easily found by an obvious search on Google, {"make someone" + meaning}. LMGTFY, if you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make

> 15a: to conclude as to the nature or meaning of something
> *what do you make of this development?*
> b: to regard as being
> *not the fool some make him*

The use you are asking about likely developed out of this meaning: to "make" someone in the sense you are discussing is to identify someone's nature. See also [Usage of the phrase "We have been made."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/usage-of-the-phrase-we-have-been-made) .

BTW, when you're mentioning a word, rather than using it for its meaning, as you are with the word "make", you should make that clear, such as by putting it in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

"to make (something) out" is the very common version we use in British English.

**Examples**

*I can't make out the writing on this letter.*

*I can't make him out. Is he wearing camouflage?*

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-out